CesiumJS Container shutting down on Windows
I'm building an application, that consists of three different docker containers. The first is a CesiumJS (frontend container), the second a Django App, the third a PostgreSQL (3DCityDB, citydb container) database. The idea is to load data from Cesium in a standardized manner.
The apps built just fine, but as soon as I open the page in a local setting on Windows I get the following error. The same network builds just fine on PopOS. And the application is running as requested. Why is the application not running on Windows?
I'm using Windows 11 Pro and docker verson 26.1.4
frontend  | /usr/src/app/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:279
frontend  |     res.statusMessage = statuses.message[status]
frontend  |                                         ^
frontend exited with code 1                                                                                                            
frontend  | 
frontend  | TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '404')
frontend  |     at Array.write (/usr/src/app/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:279:41)
frontend  |     at listener (/usr/src/app/node_modules/finalhandler/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:169:15)
frontend  |     at onFinish (/usr/src/app/node_modules/finalhandler/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:100:5)
frontend  |     at callback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:55:10)
frontend  |     at IncomingMessage.onevent (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:93:5)
frontend  |     at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:519:28)
frontend  |     at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
frontend  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
frontend  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
frontend  |
frontend  | Node.js v21.7.0

Full docker log:
2024-07-01 13:43:52 citydb    | 
2024-07-01 13:43:52 citydb    | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
2024-07-01 13:43:52 citydb    | 
2024-07-01 13:43:52 citydb    | 2024-07-01 11:43:52.866 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.6 (Debian 14.6-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2024-07-01 13:44:05 djangodb  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
2024-07-01 13:44:05 djangodb  | Performing system checks...
2024-07-01 13:44:05 djangodb  | 
2024-07-01 13:43:53 frontend  | (node:1) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
2024-07-01 13:43:52 citydb    | 2024-07-01 11:43:52.929 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-07-01 13:43:53 frontend  | (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
2024-07-01 13:44:10 djangodb  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
2024-07-01 13:44:10 djangodb  | 
2024-07-01 13:43:53 frontend  | Cesium development server running publicly.  Connect to localhost:8080/
2024-07-01 13:44:10 djangodb  | You have 19 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, citydb, contenttypes, sessions.
2024-07-01 13:43:52 citydb    | 2024-07-01 11:43:52.930 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-07-01 13:43:52 citydb    | 2024-07-01 11:43:52.949 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-07-01 13:43:52 citydb    | 2024-07-01 11:43:52.983 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-07-01 11:39:56 UTC
2024-07-01 13:43:53 citydb    | 2024-07-01 11:43:53.001 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2024-07-01 13:45:46 citydb    | 2024-07-01 11:45:46.492 UTC [1] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2024-07-01 13:45:46 citydb    | 2024-07-01 11:45:46.498 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2024-07-01 13:45:46 citydb    | 2024-07-01 11:45:46.500 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 32) exited with exit code 1
2024-07-01 13:45:46 citydb    | 2024-07-01 11:45:46.502 UTC [27] LOG:  shutting down
2024-07-01 13:44:08 frontend  | /usr/src/app/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:279
2024-07-01 13:44:08 frontend  |     res.statusMessage = statuses.message[status]
2024-07-01 13:44:08 frontend  |                                         ^
2024-07-01 13:44:08 frontend  | 
2024-07-01 13:44:08 frontend  | TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '404')
2024-07-01 13:44:08 frontend  |     at Array.write (/usr/src/app/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:279:41)
2024-07-01 13:44:08 frontend  |     at listener (/usr/src/app/node_modules/finalhandler/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:169:15)
2024-07-01 13:44:08 frontend  |     at onFinish (/usr/src/app/node_modules/finalhandler/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:100:5)
2024-07-01 13:44:08 frontend  |     at callback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:55:10)
2024-07-01 13:45:46 citydb    | 2024-07-01 11:45:46.523 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
2024-07-01 13:44:08 frontend  |     at IncomingMessage.onevent (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:93:5)
2024-07-01 13:44:10 djangodb  | Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
2024-07-01 13:44:08 frontend  |     at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:519:28)
2024-07-01 13:44:10 djangodb  | July 01, 2024 - 11:44:10
2024-07-01 13:44:10 djangodb  | Django version 5.0.1, using settings 'vdistrict.settings'
2024-07-01 13:44:08 frontend  |     at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
2024-07-01 13:44:10 djangodb  | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
2024-07-01 13:44:10 djangodb  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2024-07-01 13:44:08 frontend  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
2024-07-01 13:44:08 frontend  | 
2024-07-01 13:44:08 frontend  | Node.js v21.7.0
2024-07-01 13:44:10 djangodb  | 

